# How to do an operation on all bytes of an struct without using access any element?

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a struct in matlab with some fields each an array of double. Now I want to combine two variables from this struct. Usually I have to access each element, and do this operation elementwise. But since this operation is exactly the same for every element, I wonder is there any way to this without accessing elements? since I think it is slower. 
In other words, Can I replace the following lines

```
x_curr.u     = A * x_curr.u   + a* x_new.u;
x_curr.s     = A * x_curr.s   + a* x_new.s;
x_curr.w     = A * x_curr.w   + a* x_new.w;
```

with something like this:

```
x_curr       = A* x_curr      + a* x_new;
```

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish from your description. Can you provide a small example to illustrate?

Comment: @Shai, I edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but I wouldn't recommend it as it's messy. Assuming the field contents are scalar:

```
x_curr = cell2struct(num2cell(A*cell2mat(struct2cell(x_curr)) + a*cell2mat(struct2cell(x_new))), fieldnames(x_curr), 1);
```

This converts from struct to cell, then to mattrix (vector), and applies the operation to the two matrices. The result is converted back to cell and then to struct.

Comment: Is it the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't timed it. It may depend on your specific case (size of the struct, Matlab version). Better time it yourself

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/):

```
flds = fieldnames(x_curr);
for ii = 1:numel(flds)
    x_curr.(flds{ii}) = A*x_curr.(flds{ii}) + a*x_new.(flds{ii});
end
```

Comment: Is it the most efficient way of doing this?